# Applying a fix to multiple tags in SVN repo

Tags: svn

## Background

We have shared code libraries for which we have to maintain multiple versions (*some legacy applications can only work with older versions of these libraries*). These exist in their own repo and are imported into applications that need them via `svn:externals`. Recently we had to apply a security patch to all in-use versions.

## Question

What's the best way to apply retrospective patches to old tags from a repo structure point of view, and could the way I chose to do it (described below) have any adverse affects?

The way I chose to do it at the time was to:

1. Make changes to /trunk and commit (it was a relatively small change).
2. Tag as latest version (as normal).
3. For each older tag to be maintained

   1. Switch working copy to tag
   2. Merge in changes (essentially /trunk@HEAD) and modify as necessary.
   3. Tag local changes to *major.minor.1* (so, /tags/1.3 would be svn copied to /tags/1.3.1).

This effectively chained the tags. Since we didn't maintain a perpetual branch for each *major.minor* version, this seemed the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each tag, I would have done an `svn update` or `svn switch` to the trunk revision that has the tag, and would have created a branch from that point.

Then I would have done a cherry-pick merge from trunk to each branch, to get the couple of patches needed for backport.

Then, I would have tagged from each branch.

This way no tags get modified and you still have accurate history and a full set of tags.

If you name the branch somewhat generically (e.g. 1.2.x) then if you have future fixes to backport those also can go on the branch to save you creating another one.

Comment: The tags themselves weren't modified, insofar as no additional commits were made. The new tags containing the path were copied from the original tag instead of the trunk (for all tags except for the most recent), and that's the part that concerns me with regards to how SVN will cope with diffs and general repo integrity.

Comment: Just so I understand you, if an older tag (let's say `/tags/1.2`) was created from `/trunk@42`, I would `svn switch` back to r42, branch, apply changes, then tag as `/tags/1.2.1`?

Comment: Yes that was what I meant. Or `svn update -r42` if you're already on trunk. You could probably switch to the tag instead and branch from there but I'm not so sure how cleanly tools like TortoiseSVN would show that in a revision graph. If you name the branch somewhat generically (e.g. 1.2.x) then if you have future fixes to backport those also can go on the branch to save you creating another one.

Comment: That's the way I would have structured it with the benefit of hindsight.